# Forward Webhook Response From Postman To Another Webhook

Tags: postman, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm sending a request (to fetch a [checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) from Stripe's API), with Postman and want to forward the response to another webhook. I'm setting up an automation using Make with a webhook as the trigger so I need to have some sample data to work with and I don't want to wait until my next sale for the details from that checkout session to be sent to the webhook.

How can I forward the response from Postman to my Make webhook, in the same format as it would have had if it was sent directly from Stripe?

If there's another tool that I could to request and forward the data that's as easy to use as Postman, I'd happily give that a try too...

Comment: Maybe instead of using Postman you could use Stripe directly by using `stripe trigger checkout.session.completed` or `stripe events resend evt_xxx` to send a webhook directly to your Make server? https://stripe.com/docs/cli // https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/test

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks for the suggestion. I've wanted to do this with other services too recently though, that don't have the testing functionality like Stripe's so it'd be good to know if there's a way to forward any response from Postman regardless of the service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also developing integrations with Make and need to be able to replay webhook messages.  I haven't figured out how to do this with postman, but it's built into Hookdeck.com.  For now, I'm directing all of my webhook subscriptions to Hookdeck and then fowarding from Hookdeck to Make.  Worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks but it looks like I can't send a request via Hookdeck and then forward the response so this isn't quite what I'm looking for.